# google apps specify path for created document

Tags: javascript, path, google-apps-script, document

I am trying to generate documents based off of some user-information in Google apps.

I have something like the following code (simplified):

```
var titleAndPath = "./some/other/path/bar.doc"
var info = "foo";
var currentDoc = DocumentApp.create(titleAndPath);
var title = currentDoc.appendParagraph(info);
```

However, I can't actually seem to save to anything except the 'root' Google Drive directory. Put another way, I would like to save the documents in some sub-folder. Does the google API have this functionality? I checked the Document API to no avail ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_document#saveAndClose ).

Hopefully this one isn't as super obvious as I fear it might be!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The notion of path does not exist when you call DocumentApp.create, i.e. slashes and dots are interpreted as just another character in the file name. What you need to do is use the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) class together with the DocumentApp class. This looks like the following (untested):

```
var title = "bar.doc";
var doc = DocumentApp.create ( title );
var docId = doc.getId ();                     // retrieve the document unique id
var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById ( docId ); // then get the corresponding file
// Use the DriveApp folder creation and navigation mechanisms either:
// - to get to your existing folder, or
// - to create the folder path you need.
var folder = …
folder.addFile ( docFile );
```

Answer (score 0):

To flesh out answer above a bit more. You need to use the DriveApp class to get a folder iterator, then get the actual folder (which should be the only item) in the iterator. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769467/driveapp-getfoldersbyname-always-returning-true)

```
var title = "bar.doc";
  var folderTitle = "GoogleApplicationScriptTesting" ;
  var doc = DocumentApp.create ( title );
  var docId = doc.getId ();                     // retrieve the document unique id
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById ( docId ); // then get the corresponding file


  // Use the DriveApp folder creation and navigation mechanisms either:
  // getFoldersByName returns a folderIterator so you need to do additional checking


 var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderTitle);


  if(folderIter.hasNext()) {
    Logger.log('Folder already exists');
    var folder = folders.next();
  } 

  else{
    var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderTitle);
    Logger.log('New folder created!');
  }
  folder.addFile ( docFile );

}
```

Comment: don't forget to remove from the root folder... unless you want to keep it in both My Drive and the desired folder

Comment: The create folder part only create one folder, to create a full path with multiple subfolders levels the script would be far more complex.